# Socket resource id overflowing

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu, memory

**What:** I have a PHP script running that awaits socket connections. When I connect to the socket the script prints out the resource ID.

**Problem:** The resource ID does not increment by 1 instead by an average of 306,000. This is of course reaching a bigger problem and overflowing. Causing my code to eventually break.

**Research:** I cant find any documentation that would support me(the programmer) needing to control this. I did find the [following link](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/729100-about-resource-ids) were someone states the same issue.

**Thoughts:** I would think the system would manage this. If I need to manage the resource ID number then how do I do it.

**Code snip:**

```
<?php
chdir( dirname ( __FILE__ ) );
echo "Waiting for port!\n";
$file = 'change.txt';//change query

do{
$sock = @socket_create_listen('12346'); //port im listening too
sleep(1);
}
while(!(@socket_getsockname($sock, $addr, $port))); 

echo "Server Listening on $addr:$port\n"; 
socket_set_nonblock($sock);
echo"Awaiting Connection\n";

while(true)
{
    if($newc = @socket_accept($sock))
    {
        socket_set_nonblock($newc);
        echo "Client $newc has connected\n";

    }
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
}

?>
```

**Help:** The idea is (If you continuously connect to the socket the resource ID would overflow). My code is far to large to paste in, but I reduced it to show the problem:

A) What could cause unusual increments in the resource id.

B) If determining the root cause of the unusual increment problem is not feasible maybe how to manage the resource id could help.

**Findings:** The last command "file_get_contents..." if this line is commented out the code works correctly and the resource id is incremented properly. If not commented out and a sleep is added the increment value is much better but not correct (ie jump 5 or 6 values). Im not sure whats really going on though.

Thanks

Comment: I am confused, in your problem statement you say that the resource ID does not increment by 1. In your help statement you say it does increment by. I can confirm the latter, what exactly is the problem? I would venture to guess part of the problem is that you are not closing the socket. `socket_close($newc);`

Comment: @robbmj in the above code it only increments by 1. My code is too large to paste in. The problem is A) with That code if a connection is being made over and over the resource id will overflow.

Comment: @robbmj The resource id will still increment regardless of the close statment

Comment: you can always use one of the public code sharing sites to allow people to look at the code: e.g. **[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)**. I suggest setting a reasonable expiration time.

Comment: @RyanVincent I updated the question with a much reduced code but the error still occurs

Comment: try this link **[PHP Socket Programming, done the Right Way™](http://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/)** and see if the code works for you. I will try out the sample code in the article, here, if you still have bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not re-use resource IDs internally, so eventually you'll hit a problem with PHP using them all up, causing the warning you got. See the [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47396). Since a bunch of things in PHP will register a resource, incrementing the resource ID, this bug is easy to encounter in long running scripts.

The max ID depends on your architecture. You can print the constant `PHP_INT_MAX` to get the number for your install, but on 32 bit systems it's generally 2,147,483,647. It's significantly higher on 64 bit systems. Mine prints out 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You're pretty unlikely to exhaust the resource ID limit on 64 bit systems.

Also, you call `file_get_contents` in your unbounded `while (true)` loop. You have no sleep period between each iteration of the while loop, so the loop basically executes as fast as it can. Each `file_get_contents` call results in the resource ID pointer being incremented by 2, as it uses 2 resources under the hood. Example:

```
<?php
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #4
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #5
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #6
file_get_contents('/etc/hosts');
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #9
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #10
echo gmp_init("0x41682179fbf5"). "\n"; // Resource id #11
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on freeing your resources. I am already having the overflow problem and trying to find the root cause of the abnormal resource increment is challenging. I will hopefully have a reduced code that highlights the exact problem within the hour.

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? Are you sure you are freeing each resource (e.g. calling socket_close on each socket you open).

Comment: The resource id is eventually overflowing. That is the error. Yes I am closing the socket. On my first connection it uses resource id #5 on second connection it is at resource id #93042. This huge increase ultimately causes the program to be killed because of the memory

Comment: I updated the code with a working example of how the resource id blows up. Thanks!

Comment: @tman Updated my answer with a fix, you're not using socket_close. Try adding a socket_close before you unset the variable, like `socket_close($clients[$key]);`. Not 100% sure, but that should fix it!

Comment: Brandon the code is designed to receive multiple connections. I understand that closing it might allow that resource to be reused. I have it in my final code im just trying to narrow down the culprit of the unusual increment in the resource id. If you look at my example and comment out the last command "file_get..." the code works as it needs to. So for some reason this is causing the resource id to explode

Comment: @tman You're out of luck, looks to be a [long standing PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47396) where resource IDs are NOT reused and eventually wrap around causing errors. You should look at re-architecting your application to maybe use multiple processes that are continually respawned by a master process to avoid the issue.

Comment: Also the problem in your posted code is you run file_get_contents in a while(true) loop with no sleep, so it runs continually as the fastest speed it can. If you add a usleep call to your code it will take way longer to exhaust resource IDs.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am brushing up on my forking now...Its been a while, but I will get it. Thanks again!

Comment: @tman Also, this should take significantly longer on 64 bit systems. The max int size on 32 bit PHP is 2,147,483,647. On 64 bit PHP, it's 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Yes the interesting part is that the value of the resource id used is dependent on how long my code take to getting around to accepting the socket. Seems like this should be taken care of on the backend being that its skipping unused id's

Comment: @tman Note my comment about the code you posted. If your actual code is doing file operations on any thing else that uses resource (like file_get_contents) on every iteration of a while(true) loop with no sleep in between iterations, you'll notice the resource ID climbs extremely fast :)

Comment: I get that it climbs... my curiosity is in the why does it climb... there is no reason for it

Comment: If you are calling something like file_get_contents (which you do in your example), that's implemented using resources in the PHP core. So every call to file_get_contents uses a resource and increments the resource ID. In fact, file_get_contents creates TWO resources, incrementing the resource ID counter by 2. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you! I thought the resource id was specific to the sockets. No clue why I thought that, but I did. I get it perfectly now! Thanks :)

Comment: @tman Also see my updated comment for an example of how to visualize this :)

Comment: LOL thanks! You made my day...the whole day literally...I can sleep tonight woohoo... Thanks for your help to the community!

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt You can't use `usleep/sleep` in a websocket server. during high traffic periods, the sleeping will cause a buffer overflow in the underlying socket, because it will be back logged with pending messages. I've been battling with this for months, and your first suggestion to have a master process that spawns and terminates the actual server process on set intervals. you can use https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket from Joe Walnes github to automatically reconnect your clients. this is what i'm gonna try. i'll report back with results.

Comment: @r3wt Also you should use 64 bit PHP. It would take much longer to run out of socket IDs on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt I use HHVM http://hhvm.com which is 64-bit only. My earlier post was supposed to say that your idea of spawning servers periodically was a great idea. unfortunately my add got the best of the keyboard.