# Php resource id overflow error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP server application harvesting tweets and thus continuously running.
This application starts failing after a couple of days. Refusing to return results for a mysql select statement. I found out this is due to php resource id overflowing (PHP warning):

**-2147483648 is not a valid MySQL result resource**

This means the application is running out of possible ids to assign to a resource variable (because of the very high amount of query statements that are being fired). I figured that the answer to this question was to use **mysql_free_result** underneath every mysql select statement so that every resource eventually is freed. **This however did not solve my problem.**

On some forums I read that PHP is unable to **reuse** released resource ids. 
*This would mean the only plausible solution is to reconnect to the mysql database?*

Some information on my PHP version:

*PHP 5.5.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Mar 27 2014 16:18:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies*

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Could another solution be to use the mysqli extension instead of the regular one?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you read that they are never available for reuse? What's your PHP version?  [That behavior doesn't appear to be documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

Comment: Are you [using a db persistent connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)?  (Note, you should be using PDO or MySQLi anyway, as the old `ext/mysql` is deprecated)

Comment: This is a known PHP bug that has been open for years. See if either of these links help you. I am not the author of either article and I have no affiliation with either site.
http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php
http://brandonwamboldt.ca/tag/overflow/

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelBerkowski I am not using persistent connections. I edited my post and added the php version. I read this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043738/socket-resource-id-overflowing

Answer (score 1):

The error does NOT necessarily mean "the application is running out of possible ids to assign to a resource variable". 
Actually, it could be caused by your (if improper) using mysql_free_result() because later attempting to do something with the cleared resources would produce an error like you see. Make sure you're not temporarily "caching" or keeping resource ID's in the session and reusing them.

However, if you are sure your app runs out of resource ids, using unset() or mysql_free_result() you can free resources, then the freed ID(s) is available again and PHP could reuse these resources again. In 64 bit systems, it is unlikely you can run out of resource ids though.

**It would be BETTER to optimize the program itself not to waste the resources instead of exhausting them and then resetting. No way you can run out of abundant resources so quickly.**

What happened when you called mysql_free_result()?
BTW, if you use mysqli, you should use mysqli_result::free instead of mysql_free_result().

Comment: I am very sure I am not reusing freed resource objects. The problem was already occurring before I used any mysql_free_result statements. In the latter case the error would also immediately arise and not just after three days. What do you mean with optimize the program? How can I reuse the same (unfreed) resource objects? "However, if you are sure your app runs out of resource ids, using unset() or mysql_free_result() you can free resources" That is exactly my point since that fails to work. It seems PHP just naively adds one to the resource id for each new resource object.

Comment: Well, with optimization what I mean is some methods use more than one resource IDs. So, you can look to see if you can instead use different methods with similar functionality.