# Threaded object changing socket resource id

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a script which will accept multiple socket connections in background and do some job received by gearman (in this case forget about gearman)

```
class ListenerThread extends Thread
{

    public function run(){

        $host = '192.168.30.119';
        $port = 5010;

        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);

        socket_listen($socket);

        $client = array($socket);

        global $clientsArr;

        do{

             socket_select($client, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = NULL);
             if(in_array($socket, $client)){

                 $tmp = socket_accept($socket);

                 socket_write($tmp, "who are you\n");

                 $request = trim(socket_read($tmp, 2024));
                 echo "new client connected\n";
                 $clientsArr[] = $tmp;

                 $client[] = $tmp;

             }

        } while(true);

    }

}

global $clientsArr;
$clientsArr = new Threaded();

$listener = new ListenerThread();
$listener->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_ALL | PTHREADS_ALLOW_GLOBALS);


for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    print_r($clientsArr);
    sleep(2);
}
```

and now when I run this code and connect client with `telnet 192.168.30.119 5010` I am getting strange output

## OUTPUT

```
new client connected
Threaded Object
(
   [0] => Resource id #4
)
Threaded Object
(
   [0] => Resource id #5
)
Threaded Object
(
   [0] => Resource id #6
)
```

Why is thread or something else changing resource even there is no more than one connection?

Please note that this is first time I'm using threads so if someone has a better solution please share.

The goal is to have a background loop which will listen on port and store connections in array or object which should be accessible outside of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I'm not a thread expert but I will try to help..

First, from here: [Socket resource id overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043738/socket-resource-id-overflowing)

> A) What could cause unusual increments in the resource id?
>
> "PHP does not re-use resource IDs internally .."

*(here a similar question & answers: https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/729100-about-resource-ids)*

Second, reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php the Boylett comment:

> If you want to have multiple clients on a server you will have to use
> non blocking.

```
...
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket); // <---

while(true)
{
    if(($newc = socket_accept($socket)) !== false)
```

In php.net there are some similar working examples too (if you want to check it).

Hope it puts some 'light' to your question.

Comment: First thanks for your answer, you pointed out some thing I didn't know. Second, when I add `socket_write($clientsArr[0], "test\n");` in my for loop it only write to socket first time where the `ID` is actual `ID`, but when `ID` changes I'm getting `PHP Warning:  socket_write(): unable to write to socket [9]: Bad file descriptor in /var/www/pthreads/test.php on line 51`

Comment: However when I'm using reference `$client = &$clientsArr[0]; socket_write($client, "test\n");` everything works as it should :)

Comment: Aha, hello `reference` my old friend ;). I'm glad it worked for you!